# Entering CNAME and CNAME value into DNS for AWS Certificate approval

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, cname

I am trying to get an SSL certificate supplied by AWS and the process give me the values that I should enter into the CNAME and value fields.  I'm using Wix as our domain's DNS host.  I am getting the error message that the value must be a valid domain name but the value that AWS suppied ends w/ xxxx.aws.
Please help since Wix support really suck and I can't get a real person to help me.

Comment: "since Wix support really suck" Unfortunately we can't supplement provider's supports. Also your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. [su] could have been a better forum, but still your providers, that you pay for service, should be the first stop for any question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else coming here trying to get this to work.
The . (period) at the end of the value can be left off.  I've found a few dns hosts that append this value for you and they will not let you add it.  I was using Wix and this was the case, I also see that Linode is doing this as well.